# Need help turning standard SQL query to JPA Criteria Query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria-api

I have two tables:

**Employee**

```
id
firstName
lastName
.
.
.
```

**Training**

```
id
employeeId
trainingName
trainingSuspsnseDate
trainingComplete
```

When I perform a standard SQL query in MySQL Workbench, it looks like this:

```
SELECT e.id, e.firstName, e.lastName, t.trainingName, t.trainingSuspenseDate, t.trainingComplete
FROM Employee e
JOIN Training t on t.employeeId = e.id
WHERE t.trainingSuspenseDate < CURDATE()
order by t.trainingSuspenseDate;
```

Now, I want to create a criteria query of the same SQL query, but I am having trouble with the join. This is what I have tried based on my googling:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> employeeQuery = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> employee = employeeQuery.from(Employee.class);
Join<Employee, Training> training = employee.join(Employee_.ID);
employeeQuery.select(builder.construct(Employee.class,
    employee.get(Employee_.ID),
    employee.get(Employee_.firstName),
    employee.get(Employee_.lastName),
    training.get(Training_trainingName),
    training.get(Training_trainingSuspsnseDate),
    training.get(Training_trainingComplete)));
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
incompatible types: inference variable Y has incompatible equality constraints Templates,Integer where Y,X are type-variables:
Y extends Object declared in method <Y>join(SingularAttribute<? super X,Y>)
X extends Object declared in interface From
```

I have tried other permutations of the `JOIN`, but I get different errors. I cannot seem to find the exact "secret" to creating this query.

```
Join<Employee, Training> training = training.join(Training_.employeeId);
```

or

```
Join<Employee, Training> training = training.join(Training_.employeeId).join(Employee_.ID);
```

or

```
Join<Training, Employee> training = training.join(Training_.employeeId);
```

or

```
Join<Training, Employee> training = training.join(Training_.employeeId).join(Employee_.ID);
```

or

```
.
.
.
```

---

### **EDIT:** Added my model classes

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries(
        {
            @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.deleteAll", query = "DELETE FROM Employee e"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.countAll", query = "SELECT COUNT(e.ID) FROM Employee e")
        })
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer ID;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "name_first")
    private String firstName;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "name_last")
    private String lastName;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private String employeeDate;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "personal_type")
    private String personnelType;

    public Employee() {
        ID = 0;
    }

    public Employee(Integer id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Integer id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeDate() {
        return employeeDate;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDate(String employeeDate) {
        this.employeeDate = employeeDate;
    }

    public String getPersonnelType() {
        return personnelType;
    }

    public void setPersonnelType(String personnelType) {
        this.personnelType = personnelType;
    }

}
```

**Training.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "training")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries(
        {
            @NamedQuery(name = "Training.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Training t"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Training.deleteAll", query = "DELETE FROM Training t"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Training.countAll", query = "SELECT COUNT(t.ID) FROM Training t")
        })
public class Training implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer ID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private String employeeId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "training_name")
    private String trainingName;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "training_suspense_date")
    private Date trainingSuspenseDate;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "training_complete")
    private Boolean trainingComplete;

    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Integer ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public void setTrainingName(String trainingName) {
        this.trainingName = trainingName;
    }

    public String getTrainingName() {
        return trainingName;
    }

    public void setTrainingSuspenseDate(Date trainingSuspsenseDate) {
        this.trainingSuspsenseDate = trainingSuspsenseDate;
    }

    public Date getTrainingSuspenseDate() {
        return trainingSuspsenseDate;
    }

    public void setTrainingComplete(Boolean trainingComplete) {
        this.trainingComplete = trainingComplete;
    }

    public Boolean getTrainingComplete() {
        return trainingComplete;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the Employee and Training entities?

Comment: @SB I have added my model classes. Thank you.

Comment: A Training that has only one employee to train?

Answer (score 1):

I can figure out that You have a meta-model generated for your query.
So the best way will be to extends your entity definition as follow:

You have to add mapping in your `Training` class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
private Employee employee;
```

Then in your `Employee` class add oposite reference:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
private Set<Training> trainings = new HashSet<>();
```

Then change your criteria query to:

```
Join<Employee, Training> training = employee.join(Employee_.trainings);
```

Comment: What is `private Set<User>`? I have no user class.

Comment: It should be Training

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cross join`. Native sql is a bit differerent but the result is as axpected

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> employeeQuery = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> employee = employeeQuery.from(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> training= employeeQuery.from(Training.class);

employeeQuery.select(builder.construct(Employee.class,
    employee.get(Employee_.ID),
    employee.get(Employee_.firstName),
    employee.get(Employee_.lastName),
    training.get(Training_.trainingName),
    training.get(Training_.trainingSuspsnseDate),
    training.get(Training_.trainingComplete)))
.where(builder.equal(employee.get(Employee_.ID), training.get(Training_.employeeId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your model classes, the entities are not related directly (even though the `employeeId` in `Training` is supposed to be a foreign key, it is not defined as such in the entity relationship. So, if you wish to work with the existing entities, without changing them, you would need the following -

1. A POJO (for example EmpRes) which maps the attributes as per the select clause. criteriaQuery should be initialized on this POJO as -

`CriteriaQuery<EmpRes> criteriaQuery = builder
                    .createQuery(EmpRes.class);`

2. As the entities are unrelated, the generated query will have a cross join.

The code would look like -

```
        criteriaQuery.select(builder.construct(EmpRes.class, employee
        .get(Employee_.getAttribute("ID").getName()), employee
        .get(Employee_.getAttribute("firstName").getName()), employee
        .get(Employee_.getAttribute("lastName").getName()), training
        .get(Training_.getAttribute("trainingName").getName()),
        training.get(Training_.getAttribute("trainingSuspenseDate")
                .getName()), training.get(Training_.getAttribute(
                "trainingComplete").getName())));

        criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(employee.get("ID"), training.get("employeeId")));
        List<EmpRes> employees = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

However, if the entities can be changed (as should be the ideal design), an Employee has Training(s). So, a `@OneToMany` relationship between Employee and Training model classes should be defined as follows -

**Employee.java**

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
private Set<Training> trainings = new HashSet<>();`

**Training.java**

`@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
    private Employee employee;`

**CriteriaQuery related code -**

```
Join<Employee, Training> trainingJoin = employee.join(Employee_.getAttribute("trainings").getName());
criteriaQuery.select(builder.construct(EmpRes.class, employee
        .get(Employee_.getAttribute("ID").getName()), employee
        .get(Employee_.getAttribute("firstName").getName()), employee
        .get(Employee_.getAttribute("lastName").getName()),
        trainingJoin.get(Training_.getAttribute("trainingName")
                .getName()), trainingJoin.get(Training_.getAttribute(
                "trainingSuspenseDate").getName()), trainingJoin
                .get(Training_.getAttribute("trainingComplete")
                        .getName())));
```

You can then add the additional where clause based on your requirements.
A good reference to Criteria API is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html).

Answer (score 0):

This error message - incompatible types: inference variable Y has incompatible equality constraints - is an indication you need to carefully review DATA TYPES of the columns you are joining.  The should be same data types on both sides of the = for performance and high speed comparisons.

Comment: @Brian         Did you find your DATA TYPE discrepancy and improve performance?